# Where are the WiFi config settings stored?

Tags: raspbian, wireless

I am using Raspbian.  I would like to make programatic changes to the WiFi settings.  However, I can't find where they are located.  Where are they?  Any tips for editing them?

Also, in the "Manage Networks" of the WiFi Config, I am not able to remove old connections.  Has anyone else had this problem?  Is there a better way to config WiFi on the Raspberry Pi than this program?

Comment: Obsolete question with incorrect answer

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you are talking about `NetworkManager` settings, they are in:

```
/etc/NetworkManager/system-connections
```

If you do a `ls -l` you will see all your wireless networks there, one file per network.

If you want to delete a connection, you simply need to delete the corresponding file. If you give a `sudo cat YourNetworkName.conf` you will see something like this:

```
[connection]
id=YourNetworkName
uuid=929ceffc-8191-4dea-9a61-b4b174b9c910
type=802-11-wireless
timestamp=1218126248

[802-11-wireless]
ssid=YourNetworkName
mode=infrastructure
mac-address=00:28:F7:21:B1:19
security=802-11-wireless-security

[802-11-wireless-security]
key-mgmt=wpa-psk
psk=yourpasswordgoeshere

[ipv4]
method=manual
dns=192.168.10.1;8.8.8.8;
addresses1=192.168.10.100;24;192.168.10.1;

[ipv6]
method=auto
```

Everything is easily editable, provided that you know what these parameters mean.

For what concerns your last question:

> Is there a better way to config WiFi on the Raspberry Pi than this program?

if you need a more reliable (and maybe scriptable) `WPA/WPA2` connection I suggest to use `WPA_Supplicant` (or `HostAP` if you want your Raspberry Pi to become a wireless router) directly. I have to admit that `NetworkManager` is somehow practical, but it tends to take initiative too often for my taste, so I never use it when I need reliability.

Comment: Now, with Raspbian Jessie, you most definitely want to use wpa_supplicant. 
 There are some odd initial issues, such as the OS swapping wlan0 and wlan1 - but once it is stable it is pretty reliable now.

Comment: i can't find `/etc/NetworkManager` ?

Comment: Do you have NetworkManager currently installed? What distro are you running? Both Ubuntu 16.04 and Debian/Raspbian Jessie have `network-manager` [among their packages](http://archive.raspbian.org/raspbian/dists/jessie/main/binary-armhf/Packages.xz). You can install it with `sudo apt install network-manager`.

Comment: This needs un-marking as the accepted answer. It's (not surprisingly) incorrect many years later.

Comment: @Paul if you flash using Raspberry Pi Imager, and choose the operating system marked "recommended" (which is currently "Raspberry Pi OS 64 bit, Debian Bookworm released 2023-10-10"), then you get a popup to apply OS Customization Settings. These include the WiFi details. These get saved as a file under /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections

Answer (score 27):

Default behavior seems to consist in storing wifi settings in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`, just like @lucaslink mentionned.  I'd like to provide a bit more details however.  Here is how the `wpa_supplicant.conf` file is supposed to look like:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
ctrl_interface=DIR=/Var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
        ssid="MyWiFi"
        psk="MyPassword"
        key_mgmt=WPA-PSK
}
```

I just removed the lines related to my WiFi, leaving the `network` section empty:

```
$ sudo cat /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
ctrl_interface=DIR=/Var/run/wpa_supplicant GROUP=netdev
update_config=1

network={
}
```

And then I restarted the networking service:

```
sudo service networking restart
```

Comment: Still true in September 2017 with Raspbian Jessie.

Comment: How do you access this on the sdcard?  I am trying to trouble shoot my Zero W and it's not visible on the network.  Haven't had this problem with my other Pis.

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue, where WifiConfig GUI would not remember the deletion/removal of ssids in the Manage Networks tab. Raspbian doesn't have 'NetworkManager' settings but instead holds all network information (ssids, passwords, etc.) in

```
/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

to edit:

```
sudo nano /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
```

it's contents will look something like:

```
network={
ssid="network name"
psk="wifi password"
}
```

Once the file has been edited and saved reboot your pi for changes to take effect. Your pi will no longer attempt connection to the forgotten networks.

IF this file is empty, but your raspberrypi is still connecting to rogue networks, your credentials are likely held in the interfaces file:

```
sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

The entries for ssids and networks looks a little bit different in here, but same idea. You should see them at the end of the file. They will look something like:

```
wpa-ssid "network name"
wpa-psk "wifi password"
```

Delete/Add as you see fit.

Comment: How exactly should I edit wpa_supplicant.conf?  Do I delete everything or just the network node or just what's between the curly brackets?

Comment: @Hand-E-Food Best case is to just remove whats between the curly brackets then restart the networking service:
`sudo service networking restart` 
@Anto's answer below covers this too. Good luck!

Comment: In wpa_supplicant.conf you can remove the networks you want it to forget and leave the ones you think you want, with the SSID and password.  It will connect to the first one that works.  In my Raspian I haven't seen the wireless connections in interfaces by address.  In there it says dhcp.

Comment: You can use your favorite editor, such as `vi` to edit the file, but of course you need to use `sudo vi`

Answer (score 0):

I had this similar question some eleven years later. In my case, I have many similar devices and I want to automate cloning one to the next using the SD Card Copier utility provided with Raspberry pi O/S. I have two wifi devices, one internal and one an external usb plugin device. I found two files in /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections for the local SSID. The difference between the two files, other than the uuid value in the [Connections] section, is the mac-address value in the [wifi] section. These values will be wrong for the cloned device. To address this, I have a script to get the correct mac addresses using "ip -brief link show dev [wlan0|wlan1]", then I use sed on each file to replace the mac-address value.