# Where is the wifi password stored on Raspbian?

Tags: wifi, password

Say I type in my wifi password and press "Remember" or something. It should store it, either as a hash or plain text, in a file somewhere.

1. Where is that file?
2. Is it stored as a hash or plain text?

Comment: Check out this question (and answers) - http://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/questions/2144/where-are-the-wifi-config-settings-stored

Comment: If a device is storing a password, without ever needing further input from you, it's stored in plain text. It may be obfuscated, but it won't be worth much in the terms of real security. How could a hashed wifi password possibly be useful for a client node?

Answer (score 11):

If you are using normal settings on Raspbian it will be in `/etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf`. It is stored in plain text, but only `root` can see it - you will need `sudo` to access the file.

See [How do I set up networking/WiFi/Static IP](https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/a/37921/8697) for more detail.

Comment: Fresh install of rasberrian, new regular user can view the file without sudo via terminal